# How to prevent comments from being indexed in drupal 7?

Tags: search, comments

I've just found answers to drupal 6 to this, is it easily/nicely possible to do this by now?

I am using the search config module, but it has no setting to exclude comments from indexing. Would you still do this by altering db queries?